# Param values are not being passed to the custom controller using commandbutton

Tags: visualforce, dml

Need pro's help. Below are my code snippets. This is what I have tried
I have initialized the object **Event_Request__c {get; set;}** in my controller class.
I have created a public method to update the Event Request record.
On saving, the VF page and Class both are being saved successfully. However, I am not any data. Please advise what is it that am missing.

Input Field and Commandbutton on VF page:

**Input field**

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="WBS">WBS:</label>
     <input type="text" placeholder="WBS" class="form-control" id="{WBS}" />
</div>
```

**SubmitRequest Button**

```
<apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!updateEventRequest}" reRender="pageId" id="SubmitRequest" value="Submit Request" >  
        <apex:param id="InputWBS" value="{WBS}"></apex:param>
    </apex:commandButton>    
</apex:form>
```

**Controller class method**

```
   public PageReference updateEventRequest() {
         sEventRequest.WBS__c= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('WBS');   
         System.debug('The id for update is WBS = ' + sEventRequest.WBS__c);
          update sEventRequest;
          return null;
  }
```

Comment: Noticed that submit request button code didnt show up so posting again:   <apex:form>
    <apex:commandButton action="{!updateEventRequest}" reRender="pageId" id="SubmitRequest" value="Submit Request">  
        <apex:param id="InputWBS" value="{WBS}"> </apex:param>
    </apex:commandButton>    
    </apex:form>

Answer (score 0):

To pass data to Apex from VisualForce you should use **apex:input*** tag, for example, **apex:input**,**apex:inputText** or **apex:inputField**.

in your case, if you want to make that text input, you need to use

```
<apex:inputText  html-placeholder="WBS" styleClass="form-control" value="{!WBS}" />
```

If you want to do a lookup:

In both cases ensure that properties have public set, in first case ensure that you have doc-type set.
Also, you need to wrap it to **apex:form** to send data to apex controller.

Here you can find more information about how to use that input:
 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_input.htm

Update: After comment reread
**Visualforce page part:**

```
<apex:form>
     <apex:inputText  html-placeholder="WBS" styleClass="form-control" value="{!WBS}" />
    <apex:commandButton action="{!updateEventRequest}" reRender="pageId" id="SubmitRequest" value="Submit Request" />  
    </apex:commandButton>    
</apex:form>
```

Apex Controller part:

Define property WBS as string

```
public String WBS{get;set;}
```

And if you want to use standard SF lookup window -- just use

But ensure that sEventRequest is defined as

```
public <some type> sEventRequest{get;set;}
```

and it is initiated in constructor (i.e. not null).

Comment: Hi Kurunve, Thanks for your reply. Can you please advise  how to set the properties to public and how to set the doc type.

Comment: As when I try using the {!WBS} it gives me an unknown property error! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: The sEventRequest has already been instantiated as:

Comment: @user4435979 so, do you still have any issues?

Comment: The sEventRequest instantiation:
 public EventRequest__c sEventRequest {get; set;}
sEventRequest initialisation in Controller/Util:
sEventRequest = Utils.getEventRequest(sCampaign.ID);
Util Class: public static EventRequest__c sEventRequest {get; set;}
public static EventRequest__c getEventRequest(string sCampaignId){
sEventRequest  = [select Name, Quantity__c,SelfServ_Link__c,Status__c,Tickets_Remaining__c,Total_Attending__c,WBS__c
from EventRequest__c where Event__c=:sCampaign.Id limit 1];
return sEventRequest; }

Comment: Even after doing this the WBS is appearing as null in system.debug

Comment: Please validate my understanding of the following:
<apex:InputField html-placeholder="WBS" styleClass="form-group" id="WBS" value="{!sEventRequest.WBS__c}" />

The input field tag would automatically save the value in sEventRequest.WBS__c.
Now in Controller the following code would commit the new value of WBS:
 public PageReference updateEventRequest() {
        update sEventRequest;
  system.debug('WBS = ' + sEventRequest.WBS__c);
        return null;
   }

Comment: @user4435979 sorry, my fail. in method in controller you should use
`sEventRequest.WBS__c = WBS;`

Comment: Had a look in the console debug and found the following: 
'webkitMovementX' is deprecated. Please use 'movementX' instead.
'webkitMovementY' is deprecated. Please use 'movementY' instead.

Tried googling but couldnt find the reason. Please advise if this error/warning is not letting the update to happen

Comment: @user4435979 issue is not in that. Did you try my latest suggestion?

Comment: Yes, I have followed it. With the only difference that I used INputfield and directly binded the WBS input with sEventRequest.WBS__c.

followed by just one statement in the update method and that is:
update sEventRequest;

Comment: Please, post code on gist/somewhere externally. Pretty sure there are some issue that is not referenced here

Comment: Here is the link of code on Git: 
Page: https://github.com/SFDCGit/Stack--Code-check/blob/master/EventPortal
Controller:  https://github.com/SFDCGit/Stack--Code-check/blob/master/Event%20Portal%20Controller
Util: https://github.com/SFDCGit/Stack--Code-check/blob/master/Util%20Class

Thanks Kurunve for your help in resolving this. Really appreciate it.Ta

Comment: Basic idea is that only that apex:form is being submitted, where  button is located. So, that's why it is not being saved. check my **<apex:form>** example in anwer

Comment: Thanks Kurunve! Having button and fields wrapped in the same <apex:form> resolved the issue :)